# Clickhouse data prep for multi level sankey chart in superset

Tags: clickhouse, apache-superset

Is it possible to get the data in this format. My table is in format

```
cust_id|event_x|status|timestamp|
1      |event_1|succ  |t        |
1      |event_2|succ  |t+1      |
1      |event_3|succ  |t+3      |
1      |event_4|succ  |t+4      |
1      |event_5|succ  |t+5      |
```

and i want the data in this format to create multi level sankey chart in superset.

```
event_1|event_2
event_2|event_3
event_3|event_4
event_4|event_5
```

Pls help.

Comment: sorry, changed multi level funnel to sankey chart in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT sankey_events FROM (
  SELECT cust_id, arrayStringConcat(groupArray(event_x),'|') AS sankey_events 
  FROM table GROUP BY cust_id
)
```